# Issue starting to program for Facebook on PhoneGap (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, facebook, plugins, cordova, command

so I'm working with PhoneGap on Eclipse and I'm having some issues "building the directory" to start programming. I'm following the steps from the original page but I don't understand some points (I'm Spanish and maybe it's a language problem) I usually can manage with it but after some tries this time I don't have any other chance than asking.
So this is the tutorial page https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect I'm stuck on the Android part.

---

3.- You'll need to build + include the Facebook Android SDK and build + patch the Facebook JavaScript SDK:

```
-First run *git submodule update --init* to initialize and pull down the versions of the JS and Android Facebook SDKs that work with this plugin; they will end up under lib/.
-Next, build the JS file. cd lib/facebook-js-sdk and run php all.js.php >> ../facebook_js_sdk.js. This will create the JS SDK file under lib/facebook_js_sdk.js. Please note: the output filename is important as the patch assumes that filename!
-cd .. and apply the patch file by running patch < facebook-js-patch.
```

---

This is the command *git submodule update --init*. I'm not sure where to run it, i've tryied on the terminal in all the proyect directories but it's allways returning the same problem: *fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git*

If someone knows about this and can help me, i'd be so gratefull!!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately those build instructions are old and need to be updated as the remainder of the steps do not work. Also if you are using the latest phonegap (now cordova-1.5.0.js) you will again run into problems.

If you're on a mac, this will be easy. Just hit up the github link you supplied above. Click the "clone in mac" button. You must have github for mac installed first! Once you do so, choose the place where you want it cloned and begin the clone. Now you have the latest from master. Since I'm using the cordova (latest phonegap build), I need the cordovachanges branch. In the github app you should be able to click branches > drop down on the cordovachanges branch and switch to it. Now all the plugin code should be mainly up to date. They're still patching and fixing things.

Follow the new directions. When you get to the build + include part, just open terminal, cd to the place where the git project was cloned to and "git submodule update --init" which will update the submodules. From there, the directions should work.